# Select just one user per account

Tags: php, sql

I got this php script that should only show one user per `p`.`account_id`, but isn't working like that.

If the user have two others users in the same account, it shows as well. I couldn't think anything to fix that.

```
$groupConfig = [
'Administrator' => ['groupId' => 5, 'accountType' => [5]],
'Community Manager' => ['groupId' => 4, 'accountType' => [4]],
'Gamemaster' => ['groupId' => 3, 'accountType' => [4]],
'Tutor' => ['groupId' => 1, 'accountType' => [2, 3]],
];

foreach ($groupConfig as $groupTitle => $group) {
    $k = $SQL->query('SELECT 
    `p`.`name`, 
        `p`.`lastlogin`, 
            `p`.`id`, 
                `p`.`group_id`, 
                    `a`.`type` 
                FROM 
                    `players` AS `p` 
                LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `a` 
                    ON `a`.`id` = `p`.`account_id` 
                WHERE `a`.`type` 
                    IN (' . implode(',', $group['accountType']) . ') 
                        AND group_id = ' . $group['groupId'] . '
                    ORDER BY 
                `group_id` 
            DESC')->fetchAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `GROUP BY` clause to group by the identical value (`p.account_id`).

Why does your data allow multiple users per same account?

```
$groupConfig = [
'Administrator' => ['groupId' => 5, 'accountType' => [5]],
'Community Manager' => ['groupId' => 4, 'accountType' => [4]],
'Gamemaster' => ['groupId' => 3, 'accountType' => [4]],
'Tutor' => ['groupId' => 1, 'accountType' => [2, 3]],
];

foreach ($groupConfig as $groupTitle => $group) {
    $k = $SQL->query('SELECT 
    `p`.`name`, 
        `p`.`lastlogin`, 
            `p`.`id`, 
                `p`.`group_id`, 
                    `a`.`type` 
                FROM 
                    `players` AS `p` 
                LEFT JOIN `accounts` AS `a` 
                    ON `a`.`id` = `p`.`account_id` 
                WHERE `a`.`type` 
                    IN (' . implode(',', $group['accountType']) . ') 
                        AND group_id = ' . $group['groupId'] . '
                    GROUP BY `p`.`account_id`
                    ORDER BY 
                `group_id` 
            DESC')->fetchAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the fetchAll to fetch, or add a "LIMIT" to the SQL query. It's absolutely normal that you get multiple results. You aren't querying from table accounts, you are querying the table players. So your result will contain as many rows as the account had players. The best way would be to query the right table, but you could also solve it with the fixes mentioned before.